# what is the Rank of a Directed Graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Hi , i'm a bit new in Graph theory and i saw this definition of "Rank" on Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(graph_theory)

and i noticed that it states that the rank of an Undirected Graph is n - c

so i wondered is there a rank for Digraphs?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The rank of an undirected graph is the rank of the incidence matrix of any orientation of it. The simplest way to define the rank of a digraph is as the rank of the graph which it is an orientation of.